# Suspend to Ram - Thinkpad X1 Carbon 2017, Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: suspend, thinkpad, 17.04

Hy folks

I'm a long time MacOS user and i just switched to GNU/Linux. My X1 Carbon arrived one week ago. Config: i7-7600, 16GB, 512GB. I know how to use a Terminal, i also know some CLI commands. But as it is for now - i don't know much about Linux internals.

Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 is my Distro of choice. I did try a few other Distros (Ubuntu Unity, openSUSE w. KDE, Xubuntu, Linux Mint). I feel most comfortable with Ubuntu Gnome.

The installation went without problems and everything seems to work well. I have three partitions (/boot/efi, / and /home). WiFi, Keyboard and Keyboard-light, Bluetoth are working out of the box. Battery life is awesome, > 10 hours with browser, writing and some youtube.

The only problem is suspend to ram. It's not working. On my macs i always used to close the lid (monitor) when i was not using them. Power management on Macs is really stable. I could pick up my machine, open the lid and after a few seconds continue to work exactly where i stopped. I hope there is a way to configure my Thinkpad to behave this way. When i close the lid now, it suspends (screen turns black, keyboard light turns of, i get a blinking red little dot on Thinkpad logo on the front of Monitor). When i open the lid everything freezes. Screen stays black, keyboard is not working. I have to hard reset / power off the machine.

How do i fix this? Are there any X1 Carbon users here which get this working?

Thanks in advance, i appreciate any help.

**Update, 21.04.2017**

I got a suggestion to try a live usb Ubuntu 16.04 iso. I tried and resume on suspend works. Then i tried Ubuntu 17.04 and Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 - and here also resume on suspend works out of the box. When i boot normal, do some stuff, close the lid the system suspends (blinking light shows that). When i open the lid, system is frozen - screen is black and keyboard is unresponsive.

My config:

- Thinkpad X1 Carbon 5th. Gen (2017)

  - Kernel: 4.10.0-19-generic
  - CPU: Intel i7-7600U @ 2.8GHz
  - Memory: 2x8GB LPDDR3 SK Hynix
  - BIOS: 1.16
  - VGA: Intel HD 620 (using driver = i915)
  - SSD: NVME Samsung SM961/PM961
  - WiFi: Intel 8265/8275
  - Audio: Intel (using driver = snd_hda_intel)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/981657/cannot-suspend-with-nvme-m-2-ssd

Answer (score 0):

Could be related to a new power safe feature. 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1678184

So far I'm running ok with the suggested workaround that prevents deeper power safe states. 
I modified /etc/default/grub the line 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=6000 " 
and then make it active with "sudo update-grub " 
Se also accepted answer here: [EXT4-fs error after Ubuntu 17.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905710/ext4-fs-error-after-ubuntu-17-04-upgrade/907282)