# Disk Corruption issues after Ubuntu 17.04 upgrade

Tags: disk, 17.04

Once I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04 from 16.10, I started having disk corruption issues.

Hardware:
Z170 motherboard (I forgot the specifics)
i5-6500
16 GB DDR4
Intel P600 NVMe SSD 512GB

Partition:
1 partition on the SSD, mounted to /
No swap

Background:
I did a new install of 16.10 and was stable for 3-4 months.  I had no issues with it running or disk corruption.  I saw the 17.04 upgrade and went for it.  After the upgrade finished, it dropped me to the initramfs prompt.  I booted from a live USB, ran fsck, and it apparently fixed it.  Then a few days later, it seemed like disk access just froze.  I rebooted, and it booted to my desktop, but the drive seemed to be in read-only mode.  The only reason I knew that is because my video settings were off.  Rebooted again, and it dropped me to the initramfs prompt again.  This time, I fsck'ed from there, and it seemed fine afterwards.

I'm anticipating it happening again soon, so any thoughts would be appreciated.  Is this a bug or a configuration issue?  Would a reinstall fix it?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/905710/ext4-fs-error-after-ubuntu-17-04-upgrade?rq=1

Comment: That bug report seems to apply specifically to Samsung drives.

Comment: Currently, that is correct, only the Samsung SSD's have been identified in the problem. But I wanted to make you aware of the new APST feature in 17.04 which might ultimately effect more configurations.