# System goes into read-only mode after installing 17.04

Tags: fsck, read-only, data-corruption

After installing Ubuntu 17.04, my system started to randomly go into read-only mode. I am not sure whether the problem is hardware related, which is why I am seeking help here.
The following is the output of running `dmesg`:

```
[  153.980788] systemd[1]: snapd.refresh.timer: Adding 3h 28min 7.902429s random time.
[  153.980793] systemd[1]: snapd.refresh.timer: Adding 2h 31min 56.416202s random time.
[  153.981010] systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 7h 14min 15.923815s random time.
[  180.145338] systemd[1]: snapd.refresh.timer: Adding 1h 19min 56.064983s random time.
[  180.145343] systemd[1]: snapd.refresh.timer: Adding 2h 19min 4.310984s random time.
[  180.145582] systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 1h 7min 52.267530s random time.
[  316.563746] EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p4): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:384: comm kworker/u16:1: bg 259: bad block bitmap checksum
[  316.649798] Aborting journal on device nvme0n1p4-8.
[  316.740313] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p4): Remounting filesystem read-only
```

And the output of `sudo smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1 | less`:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       INTEL SSDPEKKW512G7
Serial Number:                      BTPY64530SB1512F
Firmware Version:                   PSF100C
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x8086
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x5cd2e4
Controller ID:                      1
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          512,110,190,592 [512 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Local Time is:                      Sun May  7 20:14:46 2017 UTC
Firmware Updates (0x12):            1 Slot, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0006):   Format Frmw_DL
Optional NVM Commands (0x001e):     Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         32 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     70 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     80 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     9.00W       -        -    0  0  0  0        5       5
 1 +     4.60W       -        -    1  1  1  1       30      30
 2 +     3.80W       -        -    2  2  2  2       30      30
 3 -   0.0700W       -        -    3  3  3  3    10000     300
 4 -   0.0050W       -        -    4  4  4  4     2000   10000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02, NSID 0x1)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        29 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    1,872,872 [958 GB]
Data Units Written:                 1,943,407 [995 GB]
Host Read Commands:                 25,786,657
Host Write Commands:                23,483,001
Controller Busy Time:               386
Power Cycles:                       310
Power On Hours:                     1,581
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   71
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      0
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, max 64 entries)
No Errors Logged
```

I've fixed the SSD a couple of times already by booting from a live-USB and running:

```
sudo dumpe2fs /dev/nvme0n1p4 | grep superblock #just in case
sudo fsck -b 32768 -y /dev/nvme0n1p4
```

Example output:

```
...
/dev/nvme0n1p4: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/nvme0n1p4: 367181/15630336 files (0.3% non-contiguous), 9061081/62520064 blocks
```

The problem, however, persists.
Don't know if related, but from the installation USB, gparted pops-up the following warning: `"The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes."`.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: For reference, my drive is an Intel SSD 600p .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Intel SSD firmware by downloading the Intel® SSD Firmware Update Tool at https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26491/Intel-SSD-Firmware-Update-Tool?product=35125

And, if this is a Dell computer, search here on Ask Ubuntu for "dell ssd" and see the kernel parameter fix there. And although it refers to Samsung SSD's, read the accepted answer at [EXT4-fs error after Ubuntu 17.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905710/ext4-fs-error-after-ubuntu-17-04-upgrade/906105#906105)

Comment: Thanks, I''ll try updating the firmware and adding the kernel parameter and see how it goes. Hopefully it fixes it.

Comment: I'll try updating my kernel to 4.11, as it appears the bug issue is resolved for that version. Thanks again for pointing me to the bug.

Comment: The Samsung kernel patch may not affect you, and I don't know that 4.11 is the right solution... yet. I'd check the SSD firmware first and see if that fixes it. Then I'd try the kernel parameter fix and see if that works.

Comment: The problem seems to have gone away. I tested it with plenty of read/write, and it seems to be pretty stable. Apparently it was a firmware issue, as updating the firmware fixed it. Thank you very much!