# Having a bunch of issues with Ubuntu 16.04 on WD Black NVMe drive

Tags: dual-boot, performance, nvme

I'm still new to Ubuntu. Would appreciate any help with this, thank you.

Here are my specs. I'm using a laptop Clevo P7xxTM1 with

- i7 8700
- 32GB RAM
- gtx 1070 GPU

I dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 and 2 other drives for storage, one for each OS. Recently I upgraded my hardware from a samsung 850evo to WD Black M.2 NVMe for my Linux OS expecting performance gains. Since then I have had nothing but problems. The major concern for me is the performance. I was expecting near instant boot, shut down, and software loading. What I got is almost the opposite. Sometimes when I shutdown the system takes a good 5 min to reboot/shut down. Boot time is much faster, but sometimes it hangs and system freezes at the login screen and right after logging in. Some programs can take a while to load. Sometimes just browsing in file explorer will cause random pauses or freezes. Not sure if this is related, but when I play .mkv files  and try to browse through the video it can cause the entire system to lock up.

Here's what my screen looks like after I hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

[image: ctrl+alt+F1]

Is this a known problem for Linux on nvme drives or was there something I had to do extra besides install it?

edit:
Here's a picture of a recent attempt of trying to shutdown and the message I get on screen.

[image: shut down]

Comment: This probably won't help but for my Samsung Pro 960 NVMe SSD I had to set this grub parameter for suspend/resume to work properly: `acpiphp.disable=1`. It has something to do with disabling power savings for the SSD.

Comment: I'm new to linux and I don't know exactly how to set these parameters. Would you link a tutorial for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks similar to the issue reported here ([EXT4-fs error after Ubuntu 17.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905710/ext4-fs-error-after-ubuntu-17-04-upgrade)), which appears to have been resolved by partially or fully disabling the APST (Autonomous Power Saving Transition) features on the drive. Try adding `nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=5500` to your kernel command-line parameters and see if that helps.

Comment: Seems to have worked, but one big problem. My windows 10 doesn't show up in the GRUB menu to boot from. I don't even see it as an option in the BIOS.

Comment: When Windows 10 disappears from grub menu, it's happened to me at least twice I use [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the recommended repair option.

Comment: never mind found my answer in another [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows). Just had to type in terminal sudo os-prober and sudo update-grub now I see windows as a boot option, thank you!