# Ubuntu 18.04 does not see PCle SSD with SATA mode set to AHCI on Acer Aspire 7

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, acer

I have Acer Aspire 7 A715-71G with newest BIOS version installed. I am trying to do Windows 10 Ubuntu 18.04.3 dual boot.

I have successfully installed Windows on my SSD (ADATA SX8200 Pro 512GB) and created an empty partition for Ubuntu. I have disabled fast boost in Windows, secure boot in Bios and I have SATA mode set to AHCI.

But when I try to install Ubuntu from USB I do not see the SSD drive...

I was trying tons of solutions online but nothing helped. Let me know if you need more information.

I'll be very grateful for any help.

Thanks,

Tomas

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem based on this solution:

[18.04 and 18.10 fail to boot nvme0: failed to set APST feature (-19)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099048/18-04-and-18-10-fail-to-boot-nvme0-failed-to-set-apst-feature-19)

At boot in grub I select install ubuntu and I press e then escape and I edit the boot option there so that after quiet splash I have nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=200

This way I was able to see the SSD disk.