# Crash on wake-up and boot errors

Tags: boot, 20.04, suspend, dell

I'm having an issue with booting up and waking up on a new laptop. I'd like to know if there are possible solutions or if I should return the device?

I've used Ubuntu for a few years now but only have a basic grasp of the more technical aspects of the system.

The laptop came with Windows 10 and I installed Ubuntu 20.04 without testing to see if the problem was on Windows too.

The problem I'm experiencing is as follows:
On startup, the system often hangs on the manufacturer logo. A restart allows me to proceed.
The system always loads into GNU grub menu. Selecting "ubuntu 20.04" allows me to proceed.
(These last two are more of an inconvinience but I suspect might point to a deeper issue)

My primary issue is this: the system often crashes after waking in an odd way. First, the system hangs on the login screen for a few minutes (Not what I would expect from a new SSD).
Next, once I've logged in, apps don't function as expected. For example, in Firefox, I can open new tabs but can't access websites.
After interacting with each app (in a limited way) for a period it will crash.
In this "mode" the system doesn't power-off from the user interface so I'm forced to do a hard reset.

After the crash and on startup, the system loads grub command line. Input "exit" allows me to proceed.

This crash after waking problem doesn't occur if I wake after a brief sleep (a few seconds).

Sometimes error messages display after the crash but not always. A few examples are:

Read-error on swap-device (253:1:1015920) (the number varies)
Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 0, lost sync page write
EXT4-fs error (dm-0): I/O error while writing superblock
psmouse serio1: elantech: failed to query capabilities.

I've updated software, flashed BIOS and hardrive firmware. I used to recieve walls of system errors related to systemd-journald but, since the BIOS updates, I receive fewer error messages however the core issue is unresolved.

I've seen similar issues attributed to a GPU drivers however I'm using on board graphics.

My current suspicion is that there is an error with the hardrive.

Specs:
Dell Inspiron 3593
Ubuntu 20.04
10th Generation Intel® Core™ i5-1035G1 Processor
8GB DDR4 2666MHz
256GB M.2 PCIe NVMe Solid State Drive
Intel® UHD Graphics with shared graphics memory

I'd like to be able to use the sleep-wake function and boot up without additional input (i.e. in grub and grub menu).

Appreciate any help!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1245762/125250

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this issue was provided to me by a user on the Dell forums.

https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/Dell-Inspiron-3593-Crash-on-wake-up-and-boot-errors/m-p/7707644#M17529

Briefly, the issue was caused by problems with ASPM resulting in the system not being able to properly wake up the SSD after suspend. To fix, "pcie_aspm=off" was added to the kernel parameters in order to explicitly disable ASPM.