# Ubuntu Installation Bug with new MSI B460 board and Samsung EVO ssd?

Tags: ssd, samsung, msi

Just purchased (Dec 2020) `MSI B460 board` with `Intel 10100 CPU` and `Samsung 970 EVO SSD`. I had a terrible time installing Ubuntu 20.04 (as the sole drive with USB boot key) but finally found this solution here
[18.04 and 18.10 fail to boot nvme0: failed to set APST feature (-19)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099048/18-04-and-18-10-fail-to-boot-nvme0-failed-to-set-apst-feature-19?newreg=76eb24244c05487a9525b06a1e615e7f)

I used the first solution of quote " **Adding as a kernel parameter** works either on Ubuntu 18.04.3 and Ubuntu 19.10. "

```
nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=1000
```

But I also see "I solve this problem by disabling `ASPM`. Add `pcie_aspm=off` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub file`."

Which approach is better?  Is this a BIOS (MSI) or Ubuntu issue?

I also had to do this edit very quickly before the system became unstable using `sudo nano ...`

The action gave stability for a few hours but eventually the system crashes and corrupts itself.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware. Even new systems may have updates. Did you install in UEFI boot mode. Since very new system, you may need very newest 20.10 Ubuntu or even add newer kernel & drivers or even try 21.04 (daily changes) even though a long ways from release. Generally we suggest LTS versions for the long term support.

Comment: @oldfred My system went for about 3 hours and crashed which was encouraging, I will check out the actions above. Yes I updated the board bios (this is what you refer to as UEFI firmware?) but the Samsung firmware only updates with a Windows10 program .... I only want to run Ubuntu.  I'll check for Samsung workaround.

Comment: My Samsung NVMe drive had a downloadable ISO which was just for my drive and was a bare bones screen that just updated to the version in the ISO. Also have an older SSD from Samsung that I could not find updates for. In the commercial area they have an old Linux version of the Magician updater, but it never worked for me.

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu 20.10. SSD Firmware was up to date, I checked using smartmontools quickly before the system might crash.  But with 20.10 my system has been up for a few hours now!

Comment: Spoke too soon, just crashed again .... I started a disk monitoring/storage app from the menu and that seemed to push it over the edge. @oldfred

Comment: It is a bit strange it works for a while. Is it overheating , check temps or hard drive filling with error messages, check logs?

Comment: @oldfred with a new 2T HDD the system seems to work fine for 2 weeks now, I sent back the SSD and will install a Western Digital one next year.  Reseated the components as well.

Comment: @oldfred   also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299149/installing-ubuntu-20-04-on-external-ssd-gives-errors was very relevant to me.

Comment: I have not been able to install UEFI to an external drive without work arounds. Have not tried 20.10 yet. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379
Others suggest disconnecting all other drives physically or logically in UEFI settings, so install drive is first drive.
Or removing boot flag/esp flag from first drive, so only ESP is install drive. (I have not had that work, but others have.)
Or if you have ESP on second or external drive, you can reinstall grub manually or Boot-Repair.

Comment: @oldfred  Wow that's a lot to think about!  Thanks for the heads up. My SSD was installed internally though (M.2) but the issue is the same for internal or external??.

Comment: Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer only wants to install grub to ESP on first drive, either sda or first NVMe drive. I have installed other distributions just to see how grub works and they install grub to sdb's ESP without issue. The partitioning screen's combo box on where to install grub only works for BIOS installs. And even unselecting ESP & selecting sdb's ESP does not work. But unselecting a swap partition does work. Others found the alternatives posted above that also work.

Answer (score 1):

Did you by chance try installing a different distro just to see what would happen?  That might give you a clue if there is an issue with your hardware running Ubuntu or Linux in general.

If I'm having a problem like this, I'll often try Fedora or another big name distro to see if the problem shows up there as well to help start narrowing things down.

Comment: I'll also look for a distro with a newer default kernel, as it sometimes takes a while for stuff to trickle down.

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu 20.10. SSD Firmware was up to date, I checked using smartmontools quickly before the system might crash. But with 20.10 my system has been up for a few hours now!

Comment: Spoke too soon, just crashed again .... I started a disk monitoring/storage app from the menu and that seemed to push it over the edge.

Comment: Does that app cause it to crash every time or was it just that app that time?

If it isn't that one app, have you tried running with different memory sticks out of the system to see what happens.  You could have a bad stick and when that ram gets used it takes the system down.

Comment: @MattMcCann with a new 2T HDD the system seems to work fine for 2 weeks now, I sent back the SSD and will install a Western Digital one next year. Reseated the components as well.

Comment: @MattMcCann  also askubuntu.com/questions/1299149/… was very relevant to me

Answer (score 1):

My experiences with Gigabyte B460M Gaming HD motherboard with a Core 15 10400 CPU may be of interest here:

1. Had no luck installing Debian Buster 10.8 / as well as with non-free firmware. Would not go past hardware check.
2. Installation and running of Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS went without issues, with the exception of occasional brief black screen (happens for a couple of seconds). Could install and run smoothly many audio, image as well as video processing applications.
3. Voyager GE (gnome version) 20.04 which is based on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed without problems and runs well. No black screen issues. However, sound did not default to intel HD audio built in. Had to be physically set. The likes of audacity, VLC, Kdenlive, OBS-studio run without glitches.
4. Today (01 April 2021) I wiped off Voyager OS and installed Debian Bullseye Gnome Alpha 1 (labelled Debian 11) using the non-free version.The installation went without a glitch and every application listed above runs smoothly.

---

Core i5 10400 CPU, Gigabyte B460M Gaming HD motherboard, Team 256 GB M2 SSD, WD 240GB SSd and Toshiba 1TB HDD on SATA.

Answer (score 0):

Using an MSI MAG B460M MORTAR WiFi board with Ubuntu then the Mint distro. I just spent some time on a more detailed reply then noticed that you are now using a hard drive which was my solution too, having had many problems with a SATA SSD. I was going to suggest a hard drive to check that the rest of your hardware was OK.
During my struggle with the SSD I think when I re-flashed the BIOS it helped a bit. 'Out of the Box' even the BIOS froze.
With an ancient 750Gb mechanical boot disk there have been no further reliability issues and it boots quickly.
It is happily running Folding@Home with an NVIDIA 1080Ti GPU as  the only configured folding slot. So, for whatever reason, it was the SSD that was the problem; I never updated the firmware though. BTW the 1050i is not cost effective in terms of power draw if the machine is only for folding.
I guess you know that MSI does not support Linux on the MAG B460M MORTAR board and Intel only supplies drivers for Windows. Consequently, and so far, I'm pleased that it works well enough and saved me £100 on Windows 10.