# Installing Ubuntu 20.04 on external ssd gives errors

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, external-hdd

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on a Samsung external ssd (from a bootable memory stick on a laptop that is already running Ubuntu 20.04).  I want the external SSD to be bootable on whatever device I plug it into.  The partitioning step is failing with errors that make no sense.  Here's my partitioning setup

[image: partitioning]

When I click install I get an error message saying no efi partition was found

[image: No EFI Partition]

If I change the ext4 root partition to efi it fails saying that No root file system defined.  If I try to make the 33 MB free space an efi partition it says Unable to satisfy all the constraints on the partition.

How do I install a bootable Ubuntu 20.04 system on an external SSD?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by repartitioning the ssd.  I created a 200 MB partition, which resulted in a 33 MB free space (like above) and a 167 MB partition.  I made the 167 MB partition EFI.  Then I made the rest of the ssd an ext4 partition with a root file system.  Then Ubuntu 20.04 installed onto the extssd.

Apparently the failure I was seeing above was trying to set the 33 MB free space to an EFI partition.  Apparently 33 MB is too small for an EFI partition.

Since I did this on a Ubuntu 20 system I didn't have the problems of fixing up the Windows boot loader that other blogs describe after creating a bootable external ssd with Ubuntu.

I'm able to boot into Ubuntu 20.04 from my external ssd on another laptop with Windows 10 as long as I disable secure boot first.  I also added my external ssd as another UEFI boot option in the firmware settings.  When I want to boot back into Windows 10 I have to go into the firmware settings and enable secure boot.  If I don't it invokes bitlocker on me.

So the only downside to booting Ubuntu 20.04 from an external ssd is having to edit the firmware settings to disable secure boot first (and then re-enabling secure boot when I want to boot into Windows 10).

Comment: Yes I had a similar issue ....