# failed to set APST feature (2) on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: kernel, ssd, nvme

Since I update my ubuntu to 22.04 LTS, I get these errors during boot:

```
Jun 13 14:37:55 ubuntu kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)
Jun 13 14:37:55 ubuntu kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
Jun 13 14:37:55 ubuntu kernel: ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
```

above error repeated many times.

```
Jun 13 14:37:55 ubuntu kernel: nvme nvme0: failed to set APST feature (2)
```

```
Jun 13 14:37:55 ubuntu kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\DPPP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
Jun 13 14:37:55 ubuntu kernel: 
Jun 13 14:37:55 ubuntu kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [IDSP]
Jun 13 14:37:55 ubuntu kernel: 
Jun 13 14:37:55 ubuntu kernel: No Arguments are initialized for method [IDSP]
Jun 13 14:37:55 ubuntu kernel: 
Jun 13 14:37:55 ubuntu kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.IETM.IDSP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
Jun 13 14:37:55 ubuntu kernel: ACPI Warning: \_SB.IETM._TRT: Return Package has no elements (empty) (20210730/nsprepkg-94)
```

```
Jun 13 14:37:58 ubuntu thermald[679]: Unsupported condition 50 (User_presence)
Jun 13 14:37:58 ubuntu thermald[679]: Unsupported condition 50 (User_presence)
Jun 13 14:37:58 ubuntu thermald[679]: Unsupported condition 9 (Aggregate_power_percentage)
Jun 13 14:37:58 ubuntu thermald[679]: Unsupported condition 9 (Aggregate_power_percentage)
Jun 13 14:37:58 ubuntu thermald[679]: Unsupported condition 9 (Aggregate_power_percentage)
Jun 13 14:37:58 ubuntu thermald[679]: Unsupported conditions are present
Jun 13 14:37:58 ubuntu thermald[679]: Polling mode is enabled: 4
Jun 13 14:37:58 ubuntu gdm-launch-environment][1073]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm(uid=126) by (uid=0)
Jun 13 14:37:58 ubuntu kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\DPPP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
Jun 13 14:37:58 ubuntu kernel: 
Jun 13 14:37:58 ubuntu kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [IDSP]
Jun 13 14:37:58 ubuntu kernel: 
Jun 13 14:37:58 ubuntu kernel: No Arguments are initialized for method [IDSP]
Jun 13 14:37:58 ubuntu kernel: 
Jun 13 14:37:58 ubuntu kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.IETM.IDSP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
Jun 13 14:37:58 ubuntu kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.IETM._OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
```

```
Jun 13 17:00:10 ubuntu nm-openvpn[15506]: AEAD Decrypt error: bad packet ID (may be a replay): [ #59175 ] -- see the man page entry for --no-replay and --replay-window for more info or silence this warning with --mute-replay-warnings
```

I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099048/18-04-and-18-10-fail-to-boot-nvme0-failed-to-set-apst-feature-19) solution but didn't help.

Comment: Any solution? I have the same issue :(

Comment: @AdrianaHernández Nothing yet! I report a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1979030 . Help me by clicking on "This bug effects me"

Comment: @MohammadMahdi I see that the bug is now unassociated... Do you think 22.04.1 (released a few weeks ago) fixed the problem?

Comment: @Déjàvu No, I don't :-) They logged everything [here](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-point-release-changes/29835/1)