# EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_find_entry:1436 Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: error-handling

[image: screen photo]

Anyone can help me? I am using Samsung SSD external disk installed Ubuntu 18.04. It appears this kind of problem when I keep it aside for a while.

Comment: Do you dual-boot with Windows? Do you know how to fsck the drive? Have you checked for Samsung firmware updates?

Comment: @heynnema Not really dual-boot with Windows, the external SSD has partitioned a EFI space. I tried fsck, but nothing changed. Feel so confused.

Comment: Did you check for Samsung firmware updates yet? What fsck command did you use? You probably need to backup your files, wipe the drive with a new MBR/GPT partition table, and reinstall Ubuntu. Keep in mind that your SSD may be bad... you can use the `Disks` app to check the `SMART Data & Tests`.

Comment: Hi Heynnema, This is a brand new  SSD, also I tried on 3 SSD(external and internal). I used fsck /dev/sd2 command.

Comment: I checked SMART by CrytalDiskInfo, the disk is showed with good health.

Comment: I'll ask again... did you check for Samsung firmware updates? If these are external SSD's, are you using USB2 or USB3 ports? How large are the SSD's? Do the external enclosures have their own power supply? Did you init them as MBR or GPT? Please answer ALL questions. Thanks.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/905710/ext4-fs-error-after-ubuntu-17-04-upgrade

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the power saving features of your drive are triggering a bug that leads to the failures you're seeing - disk io errors.

Typical symptoms are the logs you show above, fonts not rendering, and your desktop environment crashing. While the issue has been identified for some SSDs, it is still a problem for some of us. I am also experiencing this issue.

### Workaround

As a workaround, You can prevent this by adding this to your start script in grub:

```
nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=6000
```

Although, others report that only by setting the value to `0` will you stop running into the error. Of course, then your SSD's power performance suffers.

### The real bug

This is a bug that is partially reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1805816

If you want to help fix the real problem, add more details about your problem in your initial question here in SO and in the bug tracker I link to above. For example, Look at the person who opened the ticket to see what relevant info he included. I'm just starting to tackle this myself by adding my details.

Answer (score 0):

If you have special mount options (like "commit=600" ), try to mount it without them and watch whether it will happen again. 
Some people have disabled ACPI hotplug and reported it fixed it, it might (not) be your case.