# EXT4-fs error on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, filesystem, ext4

I know this question seems similar to the question in this link [EXT4-fs error after Ubuntu 17.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905710/ext4-fs-error-after-ubuntu-17-04-upgrade/907282), however, mine is different in the case that I am not using a Samsung NVMe SSD, and therefore the workaround by changing the boot parameter and also the bug report are not helping me. Thing is, I get the same errors gotten as the user from the other question.

Although mine happens randomly, sometimes when I boot the system, I'm not able to open any apllications as they close instantly, and when I try to shutdown or restart, it gets stuck and shows a black screen with an error looking like this `ext-fs error device sda 7 ext4_find_entry comm gdm3: reading directory iblock 0`, followed by a couple of errors saying `/dev/sda7: Clearing orphaned inode 6946818 (uid=122, gid=127, mode=0100600, size=0)`.

Then it shows that it is starting a couple of processes, and after showing `[  OK  ] Started MySQL Community Server.`, it shows another error `[  642.321539] systemd-journald[314]: Failed to write entry (24 items, 610 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system...` and keeps showing more errors like that forever.

Even if I force a restart, the same thing always happens a second time, then on the third time, it works again. Like I said earlier, this is totally random, some days I go by without this happening, while some days it happens frequently. I'm dual-booting Windows 10 and that works fine. I'm using a HP 250 G5 Notebook PC, Ubuntu 18.04. Hard drive model is ST500LM000-1EJ162 (DEM7).

Edit: 
As requested, below is a screenshot of my Disks page[image: Disks]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets check your file system for errors.

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier

  - `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda7`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Note**: If you continue to have problems, we'll bad block your disk, using procedures that I can add later.

**Update #1**

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

<strike>`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test</strike>

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program to do
         a read-only scan of the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added to the bad block
         inode to prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice,  then the bad block scan
         will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks found by
         running badblocks(8) will be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively.  This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'll try your method outlined here, and will update you asap

Comment: @Gozie Status please...

Comment: I'm really sorry for not getting back to you since. I've been really busy with school work and haven't had the chance to get the ISO to create the bootable drive. I'll get back to you once I do

Comment: Sorry for just getting back to you now. I'm just having time to tackle this issue. I followed your instructions and the first time it fixed some errors, and after running it again, I did not see any errors. I'll mark it as correct for now, and update you after watching the system for a few days

Comment: @Gozie If you dual-boot with Windows, download the `Samsung Magician` and check the firmware on your Samsung SSD.

Comment: As I said in the question above, I'm not using a Samsung drive nor is it an SSD

Comment: @Gozie ah yes... I misread that line in your question. Are you still running ok after the fsck?

Comment: Not really. I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and it seems the rate of it has reduced but it is still there nonetheless

Comment: @Gozie  Edit your question and show me screenshot(s) of the `Disks` application SMART Data & Tests, SMART Data window. Scroll if need be. It sounds like your HDD is going into read-only mode.

Comment: I've edited the question and added the screenshot

Comment: @Gozie As I suspected, you have hard disk problems. Please see Update #1 in my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot. I'll try it out and get back to you

Comment: Really sorry for the delay. I just tried your solution and got some message saying file system has been modified. I'll keep watching the system to see if it happens again tho. I'll mark your answer as accepted in the meantime.