# ubuntu crashed with EXT4-fs error and icons become gray boxes

Tags: 22.04, crash, ext4

I'm new in askubuntu so i hope this question is suitable. After installing Ubuntu 22.04, I found my system crashed sometimes, especially after visiting my videos on browser.

Here is the error log:
[image]

[image]

Could you please tell me the reason?

Comment: any more information about when this happens? It essentially means your system can not access the drive where Ubuntu is installed at all. Do you have the dmesg logs from the time when this happens? Is your hard drive fully working?

Comment: actually i can not even open log file after this happen... and after restarting the computer, there is no any log about the time after crash happened, so sorry for can't procide exact message... By the way, i think my hard disk work well when it is on Windows.

Comment: Possibly same issue as:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224673/ext4-fs-error-on-ubuntu-18-04