# Can't boot a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04, asus, nvme

I'm unable to boot a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 on an Asus Zenbook UX305LA Core i5-5200U with micron m600 m2 SSD with the latest version of the BIOS (300). Ubuntu 18.04 worked OK and there were no hardware modifications. I remember that I made some modifications with the graphics to be able to boot Ubuntu 18.04 properly.

Boot errors:

[image: Boot errors]

Comment: The errors in your picture are filesystem errors. Something makes reading the SSD fail. Are you affected by the [APST](https://askubuntu.com/a/906105/1127942) problem?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Adriaan. Yeah I know but first I made an error research on a windows for this SSD and nothing was founded, smart says ok... No APST workaround already tried with the two different latency and it changes nothing. I got on first boot a "Bluetooth hci0 : unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f" (not interresting). The next is ok but hang a moment on "Reached target Host and Network Name Lookups". Then it's a mess of I/O errors on ext4 and "ata1.00: status: DRDY" and "ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED" and then the screenshot I provided in the topic...

Comment: I'll try with another SSD I've in my hand and I'll answer you again with the result.

Comment: Fresh install on 128G Sandisk SSD and no first boot problem but when I've been on credential asking to log in, graphical interface loosed and guess what ? Ext4-fs errors again.....This SSD is unused.

Comment: I have trouble interpreting your last answer. What do you mean by "This SSD is unused"? Not suitable? Broken? Can you please verify your cables and maybe try another port on the motherboard?

Comment: No sorry for my approximate english. The Sandisk ssd has never been in use before. It's a new ssd, not fresh last model but new. --> everything let me think that hardware is ok, maybe kernel issue with something I can't target...

Comment: Maybe convince yourself by doing a quick install of 18.04 and check that you have **no** hardware trouble? Is the new SSD also an M2?

Comment: Hi, same thing appends with 18.04. Efi and bios mode, both generic kernel, recovery or not, nomodeset, m2 latencies tried, same result. Ext4-fs errors appears sometimes in log on screen, sometimes at splash screen. Live Ubuntu fully functional on both version and tried installing directly and from live... Nothing changes with both ssd. Need help please

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have the same problems when you install 18.04? In your question, you said that it worked with Ubuntu 18. If you have problems in 18.04 as well, then the obvious cause is a faulty SSD or a poorly seated connector.