# stuck at grub page, GNU GRUB Version 2.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I've recently got a new laptop(Dell XPS 9510) and purchased a new SSD(samsung 980 pro 1tb) and installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 on the newly purchased ssd.

I initially had this issue([EXT4-fs error after Ubuntu 17.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905710/ext4-fs-error-after-ubuntu-17-04-upgrade)) and when I followed the instruction given in the answer.. now I face grub prompt whenever I boot Ubuntu.

Inside (hd0,gpt1)/efi, I have ubuntu/, Microsoft/ Boot/, and dell/. But I don't see "grub" directory. It seems like I need to do something like

```
set prefix=(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,msdos5)
insmod normal
normal
```

but I don't have grub directory. Anyone help

Comment: So you can boot into Ubuntu? Then you should be able to do: `sudo initramfs -u && sudo update-grub`

Comment: If this is UEFI with Windows then drive has to be gpt, not MBR(msdos).  There is not a grub folder in the ESP, some other distributions may have a grub folder, but then not the ubuntu folder. The ubuntu folder will have a grub.cfg, 3 line file to boot your install. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Solved: so I disconnect SSD and put it back on, and it booted. Then, I just revert /etc/default/grub this file back to original for being safe...